# Converting floating point to hours and minutes in Perl

Tags: perl, timestamp

I am trying to calculate time based on a variable that is pulled from a MySQL database.

The user enters a number to represent a duration in hours. I need my Perl script to check the epoch time that the event will end.

Examples

```
0.5  = 30 min
0.75 = 45 min
3    = 3 hours
```

I have found that using the following in the MySQL statement works, but then needs to be parsed. I need to make this work directly in Perl but cannot find a module/plugin that does this.

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(duration * 60 * 60) AS duration FROM database;
```

output:

```
+----------+
| duration |
+----------+
| 01:00:00 | 
| 04:00:00 | 
| 02:00:00 | 
| 00:45:00 | 
+----------+
```

Comment: *" but then needs to be parsed"* Your SQL extracts a field `duration` from a (misnamed) table `database`. I don't understand how user input fits into this, or what needs to be parsed.

Comment: Are you *really* requiring your users to input decimal fractions of an hour instead of a number of minutes?

Comment: What's a *"floating integer"*?

Comment: You already have three votes to close your question on the basis that it is "unclear what you're asking". If you're quick to add some more detail then you may avoid your question being closed. Once it has been closed it will be very hard to resurrect.

Answer (score 1):

The following works with SQLite. It doesn't have the any DATETIME type, though. Unfortunately, you haven't specified how your table looked like and what the columns' types were, so I had to fabulate.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use DBI;
use Time::Piece;

my $db = 'DBI'->connect('dbi:SQLite:dbname=:memory:', "", "");
$db->do('CREATE TABLE durations (start INT, duration REAL)');

my $insert = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO durations (start, duration) VALUES (?, ?)');
my $now = time;
say join "\t", $now, localtime->cdate;
$insert->execute($now, $_) for 0.5, 0.75, 3;

my $select = $db->prepare('SELECT start, duration FROM durations');
$select->execute;
while (my ($start, $hours) = $select->fetchrow_array) {
    my $epoch = $start + $hours * 60 * 60;
    say join "\t", $epoch, localtime($epoch)->cdate;
}
```